# .NET PerformanceCounter for Hard Faults/sec

Tags: .net, memory, performancecounter

Vista's Resource Monitor includes a reading for "Hard Faults/sec". Is there an equivalent performance counter I can use in C# to get this reading? I've tried the "Page Faults/sec" under the memory category, but that appears to be something different.

Answer (score 4):

A hard fault is the same as a page fault.

Source: "[Windows Vista Performance and Reliability Monitoring Step-by-Step Guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722173(WS.10,printer).aspx)".

See section *Resource View details*, Label Memory (the 4th table):

> A hard fault (also known as a page fault) occurs when the page of the referenced address is no longer in physical memory and has been swapped out or is available from a backing file on disk.

Comment: See also https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768048.aspx#XSLTsection131121120120

Answer (score 0):

Page faults/sec measures both Hard Faults and Soft Faults.
The counter named Transition Faults/sec measures Soft Faults.
Thus, to get the Hard Faults you should subtract Transition Faults/sec from Page Faults/sec

Comment: The values don't come close to matching up to Resource Monitor using this method.